# Matlab fsolve stop if No solution found

Tags: matlab, solver

I am using fsolve in a for loop. At a certain point, it finds no solution and gives me the following output.

[image]

**Is it possible to stop matlab from executing further code if fsolve cannot find a solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just use the extra `fsolve` output:

```
[x, fval, exitflag, output] = fsolve(...)
if exitflag <= 0
    return
end
```

You can adjust the condition accordingly based on the flag values outlined in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#outputarg_exitflag)

Answer (score 1):

There's an exitflag that fzero returns. If it is not 1 then some issue was encountered:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html

for example:

```
func                            = @(x) x^2 +1  
[x, fval, exitflag, output]     = fzero(func, 0)

if exitflag ~= 1
    disp('no solution was found, terminating further execution');
    return
end
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick reply. I accepted the other answer, because it was even a little bit quicker, sorry.